# Add non existings columns to mysql query result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, select

I have a PHP variable `$members` and it looks like this

```php
$members = [
    [
        "name" => "John",
        "age" => 23
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Sasha",
        "age" => 24
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Asmita",
        "age" => 23
    ]
];
```

Now my application stores rates based on the age of people so there is a rates table with the following structure

| id | age | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 200 |
| 2 | 24 | 230 |
| 3 | 25 | 250 |

So, I am looping through all members and get this final query

```sql
SELECT * FROM rates WHERE age =23 OR age=24 OR age = 23
```

It returns me the following result

| id | age | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 23 | 200 |
| 3 | 24 | 230 |

I want to know if there is some way I can add the member to the result set so it returns results for all 3 members like this using MYSQL itself

| id | member | age | price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | 23 | 200 |
| 2 | Sasha | 24 | 230 |
| 1 | Asmita | 23 | 200 |

Comment: Age 23, 24 or _23_?

Comment: I assume you also have the members in the database, along with their age (or better for longevity, date of birth)? In that case do an INNER JOIN query to get all the results in one go

Comment: @Adyson No I am not having members in the database I am getting those from a form request

Comment: @jarlh Yeah basically I am adding a or clause by looping through all members so there are chances that we get duplicates in or clause

Comment: the closest thing I can think of is virtual columns https://mydbops.wordpress.com/2017/07/19/virtual-columns-in-mysql-and-use-cases/

but I don't understand why you don't create normal relations between members and their ages!

Comment: @omaresmaeel I can't as I am fetching those members from $_POST request, are you suggesting I should insert it in the table and then perform join each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL cannot read your PHP variable. It can only read data from tables in the database, or literal values in the query. So if your data is only in the PHP variable `$members` (i.e. not stored in the database), this will get tricky.

The easiest solution is to query your `rates` table into another PHP variable, and then merge them. You can limit the result to the age values in your input data.

```
<?php

# form input from $_POST
$members = [
    [
        "name" => "John",
        "age" => 23
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Sasha",
        "age" => 24
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Asmita",
        "age" => 23
    ]
];

# make list of ages appearing in the input
$ages = array_map(function($m) { return($m['age']); }, $members);

# list of '?' placeholders, equal in length to the number of ages
$placeholders = implode(',', array_fill(1, count($ages), '?'));

# connect to database
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=test', 'root', '');
$pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

# fetch the rates for all specified ages
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT age, price from rates WHERE age IN ($placeholders)");
$stmt->execute($ages);
$ratesResult = $stmt->fetchAll();

# transform the result into an associative array, mapping age to price
$rates = [];
foreach ($ratesResult as $r) {
  $rates[$r['age']] = $r['price'];
}

# merge the rates into the original array of input data
foreach ($members as &$m) {
  $m['price'] = $rates[$m['age']];
}

print_r($members);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => John
            [age] => 23
            [price] => 200.00
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Sasha
            [age] => 24
            [price] => 230.00
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [name] => Asmita
            [age] => 23
            [price] => 200.00
        )

)
```

Comment: Thanks Bill! I have implemented a similar solution to this

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want;

```
$members = [
    [
        "name" => "John",
        "age" => 23
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Sasha",
        "age" => 24
    ],
    [
        "name" => "Asmita",
        "age" => 23
    ]
];

$ages = collect($members)->pluck('age')->unique();

$rates = Rate::whereIn('age',$ages)->get();

$merged = collect($members)->map(function($member) use($rates) {
  
    $member['price'] = $rates->where('age', $member['age'])->first()->price;
    return $member;
      
});
```

Gets the unique ages, then queries the database for the rates, then maps over the input array, adding in the price to each member